# How do I merge two columns together in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have two columns [first name] [last name]

I need to merge them to one column to see [first name last name]

Comment: Do you need to actually merge the data, or do you just want to display the data in a single column?

Answer (score 12):

If you don't want to actually merge the data, but want to display it together in a third column, just use the string concatenation operator `&`.

```
=A1 & " " & B1
```

That displays the text in cell A1, followed by a space, then the text in cell B1.

(If you just want to mush the values from two cells together, use the `CONCAT()` function.)

Comment: CONCAT and the method you used are the same thing. You could use '=A1&B1' which would be the same as '=CONCAT(A1,B1)'. Or your answer of '=A1 & " " & B1' would be the same as '=CONCAT(A1," ",B1)'

Comment: @gui: I thought CONCAT could only take two parameters?

Comment: well look at that. Excel's version will take many, but not google's. Thanks for the clarification. For simplicity, even if it is just 2 parameters I will generally not use the CONCAT function, I'll simply use &. (personal preference!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [VMERGE](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/f3M-g6R3Bv0):

> Yogi Anand:
>
> The VMERGE custom written function written by ahab available from
>   Script Gallery to use VMERGE you have to first install it in the
>   spreadsheet of interest where VMERGE is to be used
>
> To install VMERGE: 
>  1) click on Tools > Script gallery
>  2) search for
>   VMERGE 
> 3) once found click on Install once the function is installed
>   in your spreadsheet you can use it like any other spreadsheet function
>   without any further entaglement with Google Apps Script

Comment: Hi, trying this, but don't see `Script gallery` on menu. Is it still actual with current version of Google Sheets?

Comment: @Kostanos no idea, Google UI keeps changing…